# Does the Compressed javascript files downloads faster in browser html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Does the Compressed javascript files downloads faster in browser html page.
Suppose there are two files of the same size , but one is compresses but the other one is not. so which will be downloaded fastly.

Comment: As long as the two files are the same size then they'll take the same amount of time to download. Compression, the type of file and the contents won't affect download speed.

Comment: Any explanation to mark your question correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [a number of things](http://www.yakindowebdesigns.com/webtips/downloadspeed.html) that affect download speed, but the type of file is not one of them.

1. **User Connection Speed** - This is the maximum speed that a user can download files and content from the web.
2. **Network Traffic** - There's a limit to the amount of bandwidth available at any given time. During times of heavy usage, everyone will experience longer load times. Delays of this type can occur at any point in the connection between a user an the website host.
3. **Server Traffic** - If a website's host server is under heavy load, requests are queued and answered in order. This causes a delay in the amount of time it takes for content to be sent to the user.
4. **Server Distance** - The further a packet of data has to travel, the more time it will take to arrive.
5. **File Size** - Larger file sizes require more time to complete.

In general its a good idea to compress as much web content as you can, as this reduces the amount of data that needs to be transmitted. Javascript, CSS & HTML are good candidates, and many web hosts have native commands to support this.

Ultimately the type of file and its contents [won't affect download speed](https://superuser.com/questions/530489/can-file-extension-affect-download-speed), only the file size.